# Custom shortcuts with 'Super' key no longer working (Ubuntu 17)

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10

My <kbd>Super</kbd> key opens the Unity launcher as it is supposed to do, but the custom keyboard shortcuts that I created in Ubuntu 16 no longer work. For instance, I had mapped <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to suspend my machine, but now that key combination does nothing at all.

I have tried re-setting this and other custom shortcuts any number of times without success. What can I do?